# Adding Button to a constant changeable table view

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, tableview, uitableview

I have a table view that is reloading whenever a new peripheral is found. 
I have a button on each cell. This button allow adding a peripheral to an array. Now after adding the button, i want to change it to a cancel and this what I did. The problem here, the table is always reloading and hence button is always returning to it initial state (ADD).
Any solution please?

Answer (score 1):

Do this in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
if ([self.arrayOfPeripherals containsObject:peripheralForCell])
    [cell.button setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
else
    [cell.button setTitle:@"Add" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

`self.arrayOfPeripherals` is your array with peripherals,
`peripheralForCell` is your data object for cell at indexPath

Answer (score 1):

Your table cells should reflect the state of items in your data model. Every time you reload the table, as the table view is asking for cells via its delegate you should be setting up each cell with the information it needs to reflect the current state. It sounds like you are only tracking state in active cells instead of keeping the overall state in your data model.

So when asked for a cell for a given indexPath by the table view:

1) Dequeue a cell for the indexPath requested.

2) Set up the cell so that it knows which part of the data model it is a view onto. The displays/buttons in the cell should reflect what is in the data model.

3) In your button, make the target action update the data model and not the cell.

4) If the data model is changed by a button in the cell, reload just that row and not the whole table. The reload of the row will result in the table asking for a new cell which will now reflect your data model.

This will make your cells unaffected by table reloads as you are now tracking state properly.

Comment: Yes, I added a new property to the peripheral  that is of type boolean. Whenever I press the button, i extract the peripheral from the array using the selected index, and then i remove the object from that array and re-adding the updated object at the same index and then reload the table.

Answer (score 0):

Here i am assume that you are storing `pheripheral` to `NSMutableArray`. once new pheripheral found, you are adding that to your `NSMutableArray`. while doing this you need to store `isPheripheralAdded` key with each `pheripheral` contents.

`isPheripheralAdded` has `boolean` type.

Initial `isPheripheralAdded` flage is `False` for all `pheripheral` containts. once user clicked on `Add` button. `isPheripheralAdded` flag is update to `True` and update the selected index contents in `NSMutableArray`.

Now you have `isPheripheralAdded = True` only for those that you are added. other have `isPheripheralAdded = False`.

Now while `reload table`, Add following code in you `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

```
if (isPheripheralAdded == True)
    [cell.button setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
else
    [cell.button setTitle:@"Add" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create an object and insert the objects in your array (if you are not already doing this). Then create a `BOOL showCanceled` for this object. As soon as a peripheral added then make the change to that object (on your array that you load for your TableView) and set the `showCanceled = YES`. When you load your TableView check the state of the showCanceled and set it.

```
if (showCanceled == YES)
  [cell.button setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
else
  [cell.button setTitle:@"Add" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```